# Correct moisture % when painting pressure-treated wood

Tags: outdoor, pressure-treated

I keep reading that treated wood needs to be dry before you paint it, but nobody says how dry. They say to spray on some water and see if it beads on the surface - but this test seems very error-prone. I thought I might buy a moisture meter to take the guesswork out of it, but a meter won't help if I don't know what the desired reading is. Can someone give me a number?

If it makes any difference: this is outdoors, in a climate with warm summers, cold winters, and moderate precipitation year-round.

Comment: It seems obvious but I don't want to assume, are you working with stuff you just bought? If it wasn't just bought, or bought recently, approximately how old is it?

Comment: *"They say to spray on some water and see if it beads on the surface - but this test seems very error-prone."* That can't be a test for moisture content LOL It could however be a simple way to see how 'open' the surface of wood that's been exposed for a while, weathering has been shown to allow deeper penetration of consumer-level protective finishes. Beading is very much something you don't want to see, especially if applying a waterbased finish naturally; it may also signal that the wood will be less acceptant of oil-based products, but the picture on that is unclear.

Comment: Since you posted the Q did you get any idea elsewhere on what MC to aim for, for the paint you're intending to use?

Comment: My intuition says somewhere in the 15-20% emc range for outdoor wood.